How to change AUTOMATIC1111's 'Appdata' folder?
AUTO1111 is great.
However,it has a rather annoying quirk that all external model dependencies (i.e. from HuggingFace) are downloaded and by default stored on C:\Users<Username>\Appdata. This is exacerbated with extensions (i.e. Controlnet, rembg), as every extension that has to pull a 2-4GB model dependency saves it in some jungles of Appdata.
Besides just wasting a valuable SSD space on C: this also makes backing up/restoring the installation of AUTO1111 problematic, as all the dependencies are NOT copied with the AUTO1111's folder and have to be redownloaded from the web every time I have to restore the copy or put AUTO1111 on a different machine.
Is there any way to force AUTO1111 to store all of those dependencies and whatnot in some other, user-designated folder? Preferably somewhere within AUTO1111's install folder so it is easier to backup.
